# How to know the python packages versions used by other people's Django project and install them accordingly?

Tags: python, django

I was given a project containing a number of python files without documentation. I noticed the folder contains `manage.py` so I assume it's a Django project. I want to setup the environment and run it. However, it's hard to figure out the appropriate packages.

For example, firstly I installed the latest version of deepctr 0.8.0. Then I want to run the project, it show the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'SparseFeat' from 'deepctr.inputs'`. After some research, I found it's the deepctr version issue. I downgraded to deepctr 0.7.0, and the error disappeared.

Then a new error appeared: "`RuntimeError: get_session is not available when using TensorFlow 2.0.` Then following this issue's suggestion https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/367  , I downgraded to TensorFlow 1.13

Then this error disappeared but a new error appeared: `ValueError: ('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', dict_keys(['ragged']))`. Then after looking at this issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33479 it appears the tensorflow version should be 1.15. Then finally the project can run without errors.

So I have to try different versions of python packages and search for error messages. Is there a way to know the python packages versions used by the Django project?

Comment: If there is no `requirements.txt` file (or similar files that hold the project requirements) its hard to find out the *possible requirements* to run the project. The only way (that I knew of) is trial and error method (as you already did that though)

Comment: There may be a `Pipfile` or a `pyproject.toml`?

Answer (score 0):

If you inherited from previous programmer only the code, without any of the supporting files, you are out of luck in my opinion. There are only few possible roads to go:

1. Try to manually find out which environment would work (it seems that you are doing that)
2. Get your hands on the last working example and try to get from venv what were installed packages. Even if it is a non-working copy of some kind, you can get into venv sub dirs an see what's in
3. Improve the code until it works with newest versions (probably where you want to be in the end).

Don't see any other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to run a demo notebook of DeepMatch.

Here's the fix: `from deepctr.feature_column import SparseFeat, VarLenSparseFeat`